# Windows 10 LTSC 1903: How to know what is stored in the UWF overlay

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1903, uwf

I'm managing several deployments of Windows 10 LTSB 1903 which are running Windows' UWF to protect the memory.
Since they are running on hardware that are not that performant (they have limited RAM, ranging from 2GB to 4GB), eventually they will run out of space in the overlay. The overlay is configured to be at most 1024MB and is stored in RAM.

The goal is to increase the time that the PC's can be turned on non-stop, so I don't want them to reboot once there is no more room in the overlay.
Since Windows is an expert in writing files to the system when you aren't doing anything, and I don't know where they are: Is there a way to check which files are stored in the UWF overlay.
I know I can check how big the overlay has become, but I'm looking for the location of those files to see if I can delete them once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows 10 Enterprise or Windows 10 IoT Enterprise,
you may use the free [UWFUtility](http://www.annabooks.com/SW_UWFUtility.html),
a GUI Utility for the Unified Write Filter:

[image]

I don't know if this utility will run on other versions of Windows than Enterprise.

Comment: The program itself didn't open, but it made me look to a WMI reference that should work: (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-overlaygetoverlayfiles). Currently looking into it

Comment: `GetOverlayFiles()` requires programming.

Comment: I know, I'm trying that out